# Passing an Object to component and make I mutable

Tags: vue.js

I want pass an Contact object to my ContactDetailsComponent.
Of course I want to reuse the compoent for showing but also for editing a Contact.

Passing the object as a Prop works find, but I can't manage to edit it.

This is what I tried:
Component:

```html
<template>
  <el-input
      :value="contact.firstName"
      @input="$emit('update:contact', $event)"
  />
  <el-input :value="contact.lastName"></el-input>
  <el-input :value="contact.phone"></el-input>
  <el-input :value="contact.email"></el-input>
  <el-input :value="contact.description"></el-input>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "ContactDetails",
  props: {
    contact: Object
  },
  emits: ['update:contact'],
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Usage:

```html
<template>
  <h1>Contacts</h1>
  <ContactDetails
      v-model:contact="contact"
  ></ContactDetails>
  <el-button @click="saveContact">save</el-button>
</template>
<script>
import ContactDetails from "@/components/ContactDetails";
import axios from "axios";
import {defaultErrorHandler} from "@/error";

export default {
  name: "Contacts",
  components: {ContactDetails},
  data() {
    return {
      contact: {
        id: null,
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        phone: null,
        description: null,
        email: null,
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
        .post(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL + "contact/getById", 1)
        .then(res => {
          this.contact = res.data
        })
        .catch(defaultErrorHandler)
  },
  methods: {
    saveContact() {
      console.log(this.contact)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I now when I write something in the firstName field I get this at the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "contact". Expected Object, got String with value "FirstNamea". 
  at <ContactDetails contact="FirstNamea" onUpdate:contact=fn > 
  at <Contacts onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref<
```

But I can't update the contact object and return it, how should I do this.

This is how res.data looks:

```
Object { id: 1, firstName: "FirstName", lastName: "LastName", email: "test@test.net", description: "description", phone: "12345678" }
```

Thank you for your help.

PS: I am using the [element-framework](https://element-plus.org/#/en-US).

Comment: Looks like `this.contact = res.data` is assigning the wrong data. What happens if you add a `console.log(res.data)` statement after that? What does `res.data` look like?

Comment: This error is because parent component expect Object on update event from child, but you give him string from here `@input="$emit('update:contact', $event)"`. Instead `$event` you should put entire `contact` object with already updated `firstName` value.

Comment: To avoid this, use `v-model`, for each `contact` property.

Comment: @bassxzero added the response. But this should not be a problem because the properties are shown correctly just editing is a problem.

Comment: @AceofSpade Sorry I didn't see that the error was from the update method. Radeanu is correct.

Comment: @Radeanu but where do I get the contact object with the updated value, do I need to make a copy into data?

Comment: @AceofSpade noo, try like so: `{...contact, firstName: $event}`

Comment: But I recommend to use `v-model` for each `contact` values, it will be more readable

Comment: @Radeanu I don't want to do v-model for each object because I have to do It each time I use the component. I want to reuse the code.

Comment: @Radeanu adding `"$emit('update:contact', {...contact, firstName: $event})"` has the effect that the text-filed gets empty and only one character I set is in the object. Do you know why get this happens?

Comment: Maybe you missed something, see example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-monad-v5xgj?file=/src/components/ContactDetails.vue

Comment: @Radeanu really thanks for you effort,  a plain input it works as expected, el-input seams to be the problem .

Comment: Use `:modelValue` instead of `:value` because `el-input` doesn't suport value attribute

Comment: @Radeanu thank you really much, if you post an answer I will mark it as solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236722/discussion-between-radeanu-and-ace-of-spade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just to mark this question as solved:

```js
<template>
  <el-input
      :modelValue="contact.firstName"
      @input="$emit('update:contact', {...contact, firstName: $event})"
  />
  <el-input
      :modelValue="contact.lastName"
      @input="$emit('update:contact', {...contact, lastName: $event})"
  />
  <el-input
      :modelValue="contact.phone"
      @input="$emit('update:contact', {...contact, phone: $event})"
  />
  <el-input
      :modelValue="contact.email"
      @input="$emit('update:contact', {...contact, email: $event})"
  />
  <el-input
      :modelValue="contact.description"
      @input="$emit('update:contact', {...contact, description: $event})"
  />
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "ContactDetails",
  props: {
    contact: Object
  },
  emits: ['update:contact'],
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use other custom components in ContactDetails  and pass child a object of the contact prop to it? I tried an got an unexpexted mutation error from vue.